# Fadeout all nested divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadeout

On my page I'm trying to do smth like that: Lets say, when we click on some link with id `min_reg` it animates div with id`ftr_form_cntr`, and shows another div `tcr_form_cntr` within.

There are 3-4 links that does same function but shows another div within `ftr_form_cntr`. Well if user clicked one of this links for the first time then there is no problem. But if user already clicked (I mean if `ftr_form_cntr` already opened) I want to just fadeOut all existing divs nested to `ftr_form_cntr` and fade in one another div (or swap existing div with another one).

Take a look at this line `tcr_form_cntr.fadeIn(1000)`. What do I need to do before this line to fadeOut all nested divs?

My function look like this:

```
$(min_reg).click(function () {
    if($(ftr_form_cntr).hasClass('opened')){  
        $(ftr_form_cntr)...<fadeOut all nested divs>
        tcr_form_cntr.fadeIn(1000);
        return;
    }
    ftr_form_cntr.show().stop(true, true).animate({
        height:"170"
    },1000).addClass('opened');
    tcr_form_cntr.fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `ftr_form_cntr` is a string variable holding the jQuery selector for your container element, you can select all the div elements inside and fade them like this:

```
$(ftr_form_cntr + " div").fadeOut();
```

Have a look at [the jQuery doco on selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), specifically the ["descendant selector"](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/).

If `ftr_form_cntr` is not a string variable but is actually, say, a reference to a DOM element or something then another way to select certain nested elements is using the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method, which gets descendants of the elements in your existing jQuery object according to another selector you provide:

```
$(ftr_form_cntr).find("div").fadeOut();
```

Comment: Cool. Note that the code in the question seems a bit confused about what `ftr_form_cntr` is: it seems to be a jQuery object because at one point you access jQuery methods directly - `ftr_form_cntr.show()`  but before that you are treating it as a selector - `$(ftr_form_cntr)` - which will work too, but is not needed if you've previously said `var ftr_form_cntr = $("some selector");`.

Comment: I'm new to js. Cached div before function to var. Is there any diff. between $(ftr_form_cntr) and ftr_form_cntr?

Answer (score 0):

Your function could look like this:

```
$(min_reg).click(function () {
    var animated_div = $(ftr_form_cntr);
    if(animated_div.hasClass('opened')){  
        animated_div.find('div').fadeOut();
        tcr_form_cntr.fadeIn(1000);
        return;
    }
    animated_div.show().stop(true, true).animate({
        height:"170"
    },1000).addClass('opened');
    tcr_form_cntr.fadeIn(1000);
});
```

What I did is:

- I **cached the element** you work on (`$(ftr_form_cntr)`),
- used `.find()` jQuery method to **get all the divs** you want to fade out,

Did it help? Please **make sure that both `ftr_form_cntr` and `tcr_form_cntr` are defined** and first is **eg. selector**, but the **second must be jQuery object**.

Comment: Can I do it without hasclass but with visible?

Comment: Yes, if you want to determine the visibility. Just use [`.is(:visible)` jQuery call](http://api.jquery.com/is/).